# " People Who Liked this Also Liked " Query in Mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, associations, bayesian

`Music table`

```
id | title
1    Rap God
2    Blank Space
3    Bad Blood
4    Speedom
5    Hit 'em up
```

`Like table`

```
u_id | m_id
1      1
1      2
1      4
1      5
2      3
2      4
2      5
3      1
3      5
4      1
4      2
4      5
```

Now if someone visits `music` with `m_id = 1`

Then the output might be like

```
   m_id

    5
    2
    4
```

**To explain this a bit...**

As `m_id = 1` is liked by `users -> {1,3,4}`  which in turn `likes ->{2,4,5}` musics. Since `m_id=5` is liked by max number of users its first followed by `m_id = 2` and `m_id = 4`.

**My Try**

- I queried the users who liked `m_id = 1`

  `SELECT u_id FROM likes WHERE m_id =1`
- Then i stored in in an array and selected each of their likes and
  arranged them in desc order of count.

But it is a very slow and long process is there any way i can do this ?

**p.s** I have heard of `Association Rules` and `Bayesian theorem` can be user to achieve this. But can anyone help me out with an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `JOIN` back on the `Like` table and do something like this.

```
SELECT also_like.m_id, COUNT(also_like.m_id)
FROM [like] AS did_like
JOIN [like] AS also_like ON
    also_like.u_id = did_like.u_id
    AND also_like.m_id != did_like.m_id
WHERE did_like.m_id = 1
GROUP BY also_like.m_id
ORDER BY COUNT(also_like.m_id)
```

Essentially you are getting a list of users who liked an item then getting a complete list of those user's likes excluding the item they just liked.

You can then add a `HAVING` clause or `LIMIT` to filter things down a bit more.

Comment: That query works surprisingly well. I populated `like` table with 30k rows for 10k users and 10k items and the results are more or less instant. It is probably useful to add a `COUNT(*)` to the SELECT and ORDER clauses for ranking purposes as well.

Answer (score 0):

using a subquery ...

```
SELECT m_id, count(u_id) as Rank FROM `like`
WHERE u_id in
(
   SELECT u_id
   FROM `like`
   WHERE m_id = 1
)
AND m_id <> 1
GROUP BY m_id
ORDER BY Rank DESC
```

and optionally

```
LIMIT 0, 10
```

or how many "alsolikes" you want to display